# trying to rebuild a Reddit Rails App from two years ago (User Agent & BootStrap)

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0

Two years I used the Reddit API to pull stories into a Rails app I built. I wanted to come back to it to refresh myself on RoR. It seems like I got all of the updates working and can sometimes run it, but here are my issues:

1) Reddit now requires Oauth2 for API requests. I'm using the Redd gem and am able to get authenticated, but I get the 429 error (too many requests) error.

I copied from the Redd instructions the following into my model (substituting my info from my registered Reddit app page):

```
# Authorization (Web)
w = Redd.it(:web, "_myClientId_", "_My_Secret", "_myRedirectURI", user_agent: 'ruby:edswartz.com.myredditapp:v1.0 (by /u/edswartz')
url = w.auth_url("random_state", ["identity", "read"], :permanent)
puts "Please go to #{url} and enter the code below:"
code = gets.chomp
w.authorize!(code)

# Authorization
re = Redd.it(:script, "_my_Client_ID_", "_my_secret_", "_my_user_name_", "_my_password_", user_agent: 'ruby:edswartz.com.myredditapp:v1.0 (by /u/edswartz')
re.authorize!

edAgent = 'User-Agent: ruby:com.edswartz.trueQuotes:v1.0 (by /u/edswartz)'

response = JSON.load(RestClient.get('http://reddit.com/.json'),{'User-Agent'=> edAgent})
```

After successfully authenticating (copying and pasting the code into the console) I usually get a 429 error. What am I doing wrong? I'm not trying to spoof the user agent, but have put it in manually. I just don't know how else to do it.

The times that I do get in and see the site appear it is obvious that Bootstrap has not loaded. In looking at the Rails-Bootstrap documentation I see where the Gem name has changed and the application css. My /app/assets/stylesheets/application css looks like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
@import "bootstrap";
 */
```

Again, not sure this is right either but have tried to comply with the read me from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

Any help anyone can provide on either of these issues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the Bootstrap question. I was using Bootstrap 4. When I went back to Bootstrap 3, and moved the @import directives in the SASS file out of the comments section AND changed the "span4" class to "col-md-4" everything worked.

The user agent seems to be working more often so it might have been a caching issue?

In any event, onward.